# running red5 on static ip of vps with 80 port

Tags: apache, centos, red5

As per the basic requirements of av chat, we have installed red5 media server on our linux vps running cents os.

after installation and starting red5 we have check if the red5 is running on our ip address by http://ouripaddress:5080 and we got the red5 page... then after we have install ssl certificate on our server and reconfigure red5 for ssl.

after all configuration and changing the ports in red5.properties file from 5080 to 80 when we tried to test it again... by http://ouripaddress:80 it open our site page not the red5 one.

all the ports that are required are open... but now we are not sure that we can go ahead to install av chat or not please provide support. what should we do in this situation to use avchat on our server..

can we use avchat with the 5080 port configuration of red5 for our website.. or its required to use the 80 number port and 443 for ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on avchat, but if you set http.port in red5 to 80 instead of 5080 and you got some other webpage, it means you have another http server running on port 80 and answering requests. Port 80 is the default for http and port 443 is the default for https, but they are not required to be on those ports.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as per your reply "... they are not required to be on those ports."  did u mean to say that red5 ports that is 5080 and 5443 are not required to be on 80 and 443..?